# How does this Clojure form work? Removing a list from another list

Tags: clojure

I am doing a project for class and I stumbled upon some code that has proved useful, though I am not sure how the line below "reads". I understand the result of what it does, but not how it does it.

```
(remove #(some (partial = %) '(1 2 3 4)) '(1 2 3 5 6 7))
```

What it does is removes the values from the second set that are in the first if possible. So given two set `P` and `V` it finds `P / V`.

I guess I am looking for an English language sentence of what is happening?

Edit: Title. Also I do understand what remove does, given some predicate such as `pos?` it returns a lazy sequence of items that equate to true when the predicate is applied.

What I specifically do not understand is how `#(some (partial = %))` evaluates to a predicate.

Comment: Eh? These are lists, not sets. `#{1 2 3 4}` would be a set, and there would be much more efficient native operations for doing set logic with them.

Comment: Beyond that -- it'd be helpful if you wrote out what you *do* know/understand, so folks answering this know what doesn't need to be answered. Do you know what `#(foo %)` does? Do you know what `remove` does? Do you know what `partial` does? Etc.

Comment: I made some edits to reflect those issues.

Comment: As usually - read clojure code inside-out `#(some (partial = %))` -> What `partial` is for? What `(partial = value)` is for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#(some (partial = %) '(1 2 3 4))
```

...is syntax sugar for...

```
(fn [x] (some (partial = x) '(1 2 3 4))
```

...so, calling

```
(#(some (partial = %) '(1 2 3 4)) 5)
```

...runs...

```
(some (partial = 5) '(1 2 3 4))
```

...thus, running `(partial = 5)` against every entry in `'(1 2 3 4)` until it finds a match -- thus: `(= 5 1)`, `(= 5 2)`, etc -- and returning `nil` when no match is returned.

`nil` is falsey. Thus, any sequence element for which no match exists will return false, and be retained by `remove`, whereas for anything with which a match exists, the predicate will return true and be removed.

---

Obviously, creating a lambda function for every item in one of your sequences and evaluating those functions against content of another sequence is *extremely* inefficient compared to real set arithmetic. Thus, this code shouldn't be used in any case where the number of items might be nontrivial.

Instead:

```
(clojure.set/difference
  #{1 2 3 4 5 6 7}
  #{1 2 3 4})
```

...would be the efficient and idiomatic approach. If you're starting with a list rather than a set literal, that might be replaced with `(clojure.set/difference (into #{} list-a) (into #{} list-b))` or `(clojure.set/difference (set list-a) (set list-b))`.